# PostgreSQL - integer[] best practice

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, ibatis

Working on a web app lately I decided to use integer[] in the data model. Having 2 tables, one with articles' data and a second with tags (tag id and description), decided to the tag ids an article would be tagged with in a article.tags integer[] column.

As [Milen A. Radev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15785/milen-a-radev) pointed out:

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

Not only that, but having to work with integer[] using JDBC and iBatis turned out, shall I say "interesting".

For the moment, I can get away with the working implementation in place for what I had to do. It will probably get re-worked for simplicity's sake using a separate table storing article.id and tag.id relationships.

In the end I'm puzzled by what is integer[] best used for and in what context?

I think I figured out the hard way what it's not best for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, since any array is a violation of 1NF, the best context is:... (drumroll)..... none.

This gets to the question of why we would have data that is not meant to be queried.  All values are potentially searchable, and if we are not supposed to use an array on searchable values, we are again led to the conclusion it is never worth using.

This leaves only a hypothetical case where you are storing an array solely for the purpose of analysis and manipulation on the client.  I'm sure these exist, but not in my experience.

**EDIT:** Above I said, "I'm sure these exist..."  Look at @mu is too short's answer for an example.

Answer (score 6):

I've used arrays in PostgreSQL when dealing with tree structures such as comment threads. You can store the path from the root to your node as an array of branch numbers. Then, pulling out the whole tree in the correct display order is a simple matter of:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM comments
WHERE thread = X
ORDER BY path -- This would be the array.
```

PostgreSQL compares arrays in the only sensibly way. Using an array for the path from the root also gives you an easy way to compute the depth of a node. You could use a string (with say 3 base-96 digits per branch number) and ASCII-betical sorting for the same purpose but an array is a lot clearer.

Yes, there are other ways of dealing with trees that are more pedantically correct but using an array offered a crystal clear implementation. If I was doing a lot of tree manipulation then maintaining the path arrays would involve a lot of busy work so I'd probably go with a different representation.

Not exactly Java-specific but there are cases where arrays are a natural and useful representation (even in SQL) of the data at hand.

Comment: Fantastic example.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of three applications:

The first is for denormalization.  Tradeoffs include: You can't easily update or process the elements individually.  But it's easy and quick to fetch all of them at once.  It also saves a lot of space.

The second, slightly related, is that you use arrays not for storage but for some intermediate processing.  For example, if you want to process data in batches in a non-SQL-ish language that doesn't handle proper sets easily.

The third is for storing an ordered list of data.  I have come across a few applications like that, but it's hard to put a finger on it.  Of course you can also represent that in a table with an extra column for the position, but sometimes this doesn't make much sense because you don't need to access the individual pieces separately in the database.  In some cases, this is just a list that the client application wants to store and retrieve later.

But your overall sense is right.  If you don't know better, your first instinct should probably be not to use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

integer[] would be good for a conversion table. Where the key is the index, and it is known that every index has a value, or there is someway to represent empty positions (like -1). I would think in this case it would be faster than a foreign key.

Another use would be a chart. What's the result per test run. Test runs have 6 results. is a row, the integer[] is the array of 6 results.

Answer (score 0):

IFF the array is a value as a whole, I would potentially consider using the array datatype. But when is an array only a value as a whole? I don't really know.

Maybe when it would *only* make more sense to search for the value as a whole. Having a table that should contain exactly the items you are searching for before you want to know the corresponding row doesn't seem to make much sense. So if you want to search for the complete array as key.