# Is it bad design to use arrays within a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

So I'm making a database for a personal project just to get more than my feet wet with PostgreSQL and certain languages and applications that can use a PostgreSQL database.

I've come to the realization that using an array isn't necessarily even compliant (Arrays are not atomic, right?) with 1NF. So my question is: Is there a lack of efficiency or data safety this way? Should I learn early to not use arrays?

Comment: Who says an array is not atomic? I've never read that statement in the manual.

Comment: Having a cell contain multiple values is not atomic in design from what I've read. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) has an example.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20005804/storing-structured-data-in-a-database-column/20006970#20006970
q/a.; the same applies to arrays too. As long the DB support the data type and has matching set of operators, all is good.

Comment: There are good answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797323 (PostgreSQL - integer[] best practice)

Comment: Also note that arrays are updated atomically (it's impossible to update just one element) which totally differs from an array in a programming language.

Comment: Actually, arrays **are** compliant with the SQL standard. `create table foo (readings integer array[5])` **is** part of the SQL standard

Comment: Note to self: You can always transform rows into an array when retrieving the data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601952/9157799

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Short answer to the title**: No

**A bit longer answer**:

You should learn to use arrays when appropriate. Arrays are not bad design themselves, they are as atomic as a character varying field (array of characters, no?) and they exists to make our lives easier and our databases faster and lighter. There are issues considering portability (most database systems don't support arrays, or do so in a different way than Postgres)

Example:

You have a blog with posts and tags, and each post may have 0 or more tags. The first thing that comes to mind is to make a different table with two columns `postid` and `tagid` and assign the tags in that table.

If we need to search through posts with tagid, then the extra table is necessary (with appropriate indexes of course).

But if we only want the tag information to be shown as the post's extra info, then we can easily add an integer array column in the table of posts and extract the information from there. This can still be done with the extra table, but using an array reduces the size of the database (no needed extra tables or extra rows) and simplifies the query by letting us execute our select queries with joining one less table and seems easier to understand by human eye (the last part is in the eye of the beholder, but I think I speak for a majority here). If our tags are preloaded, then not even one join is necessary.

The example may be poor but it's the first that came to mind.

**Conclusion**:

Arrays are not necessary. They can be harmful if you use them wrong. You can live without them and have a great, fast and optimized database. When you are considering portability (e.g. rewriting your system to work with other databses) then you must not use arrays.

If you are sure you'll stick with Postgres, then you can safely use arrays where you find appropriate. They exist for a reason and are neither bad design nor non-compliant. When you use them in the right places, they can help a little with simplicity of database structures and your code, as well as space and speed optimization. That is all.

Comment: For portability reason you can substitute easily the bad performances of PG arrays by some XML or JSON. Other big RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle) can indexes those datatype for performances, that PG cannot !

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you're saying if you need a query like `SELECT * FROM Post WHERE :tagID = ANY(tagIDs)` then a `tagIDs` array is the wrong choice?

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **Yes, it is bad design.** Using arrays will guarantee that your design is not 1NF, because to be 1NF there must be no repeating values. Proper design is unequivocal: make another table for the array's values and join when you need them all.

Arrays may be the right tool for the job in certain limited circumstances, but I would still try hard to avoid them. They're a feature of last resort.

The biggest problem with arrays is that they're a crutch. You know them already and you want to use them because they're familiar to you. But they do not work quite like you expect, and they will only allow you to postpone a true understanding of SQL and relational databases. You're much better off waiting until you're forced to use them than learning them and looking for opportunities to rely on them.

Comment: Arrays in postgres as an intermediate representation in queries allow to transfer rows into columns and columns into rows and move that from one level of subquery to the next. It's a feature that actually push the envelope of SQL in a powerful and elegant way. Trying hard to avoid them is a mistake, except for portability concerns with other SQL engines.

Comment: @Daniel_Vérité some other RDBMS uses XML that can be indexed for the sames features as you said, but much more efficiently because XML can be indexed (SQL Server, Oracle) that cannot PostGreSQL. See : http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Answer (score 5):

Whether an array is atomic depends on what you're interested in. If you generally want the whole array then it's atomic. If you are more interested in the individual elements then it is being used as structure. A text field is basically a list of characters. However, we're usually interested in the whole string.

Now - from a practical viewpoint, many frameworks and ORMs don't automatically unpack PostgreSQL's array types. Also, if you want to port the database to e.g. MySQL then you'll

Likewise foreign-key constraints can't be added to an array (EDIT: this is still true as of 2021).

Answer (score 1):

I believe arrays are a useful and appropriate design in cases where you're working with array-like data and want to use the power of SQL for efficient queries and analysis. I've begun using PostgreSQL arrays regularly for data science purposes, as well as in PostGIS for edge cases, as examples.

In addition to the well-explained challenges mentioned above, I'm finding the biggest problem in getting third-party client apps to be able to handle the array fields in ways I'd expect. In Tableau and QGIS, for example, arrays are treated as strings, so array operations are unavailable.

Arrays are a first class data type in the SQL standard, and generally allow for a simpler schema and more efficient queries. Arrays, in general, are a great data type. If your implementation is self-contained, and doesn't need to rely on third-party tools without an API or some other middleware that can deal with incompatibilities, then use the array field.

IF, however, you interface with third-party software that directly queries the DB, and arrays are used to produce queries, then I'd avoid them in favor of simpler lookup tables and other traditional relational approaches.