# Postgres with Knex - query where an array contains a particular value

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Surprising as it is, I haven't been able to figure out how to return a table that has an array that contains a particular value using knex. I see in the Postgres docs it's possible.

in sql

```
SELECT ... FROM fdt WHERE c1 IN (1, 2, 3)
```

but I can't find how this would be done with knex. One suggestion online was using whereIn.

So I tried

```
knex.from('pin_table').select('*').whereIn('likes_recieved', id)
 .whereIn('likes_sent', id)
```

(I also tried whereIn with the array and search parameter switched like .whereIn(id, 'likes_recieved')

but I keep getting back a syntax error:

```
"select * from "pin_table" where "10" in $1 and "10" in $2 - syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this with knex or knex.raw?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends a bit on whether you're using the [`ARRAY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/arrays.html) type, or if `likes_sent` is built from a subquery etc. If it's an array, you're probably going to need to use `ANY`:

```
knex.from('pin_table').whereRaw('? = ANY(likes_received)', id);
```

That's a best guess without seeing your schema. Usually I'd be tempted to use a separate table rather than the Postgres array:

```
knex('pin_table as p')
  .join('likes as l', 'p.id', 'l.pin_id')
  .where('l.user_id', id);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20220450/122643 for a discussion of potential pitfalls and advantages of Postgres arrays.

Comment: Looks like that worked, and good tip about the separate table.. I'll keep that in mind in the future.